# How can I access the data for the Android calendar app on my phone?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, calendar, samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini, app-data

I have been using the Calendar app on my android phone, and I want to access the data for this app so that I can export it. I cannot find a "com.android.calendar" folder, nor can I find any file or directory with "calendar" anywhere in the name. Where would I find it?

Here's why I want the data: Although the android calendar app "syncs" with my Google calendar account (as in, events on my google calendar appear on my phone), any events that I added through the app on the mobile device do not get uploaded to my Google calendar. After a while, I realized that I should use the "Google Calendar" app instead of the default "Calendar" app that came with the phone. But I would like to export the events from the android calendar to my Google calendar. Is there an easy way to export the data from the Android calendar app to the Google calendar? It appears that at least one other person has had [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834257/sync-from-android-phones-calendar-to-google-calendar-on-web-without-using-googl).

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 mini with android version 4.4.2.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you don't have root access. If you've that, look into `/data/data`.

The folder you're looking for is at `/data/data/com.android.calendar/` but the stuff you need is under `/data/data/com.android.providers.calendar`.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

For rootless extraction, you'll need to rely on ADB Backup or other natively supported option (Google Backup, Samsung Smart Switch, etc.).  On my Samsung Note 8, assuming the Calendar app has the same `manifest.xml` flags, AllowBackup flag is present, which means you can use ADB to perform the application backup and restore.  (Note: there are many guides here on ASU regarding ADB's usage, you can also check XDA for further guidance).